# Error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed after the while loop?

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

Hello i have a method which reads some data from the sql and saves them to arrays.

to find out how many rows the sql result has i wrote this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(rdr);
            count = dt.Rows.Count;
```

after that, the sqldatareader saves the results to arrays.

here is my complete code:

```
 public BookingUpdate[] getBookingUpdates(string token)
{
    String command = "SELECT b.ID,b.VERANSTALTER, rr.VON ,rr.BIS, b.THEMA, b.STORNO, ra.BEZEICHNUNG from BUCHUNG b JOIN RESERVIERUNGRAUM rr on rr.BUCHUNG_ID = b.ID JOIN RAUM ra on ra.ID = rr.RAUM_ID WHERE b.UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD (DAY , -20 , getdate()) AND getdate() AND b.BOOKVERNR = 0";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    BookingUpdate[] bookingupdate = new BookingUpdate[1];
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        int count = 0;
        int c = 0;

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        count = dt.Rows.Count;
        bookingupdate = new BookingUpdate[count];

        while (rdr.Read())   // <--- HERE COMES THE ERROR
        {
                bookingupdate[c] = new BookingUpdate();
                bookingupdate[c].bookingID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
                bookingupdate[c].fullUserName = rdr["VERANSTALTER"].ToString();
                bookingupdate[c].newStart = (DateTime)rdr["VON"];
                bookingupdate[c].newEnd = (DateTime)rdr["BIS"];
                bookingupdate[c].newSubject = rdr["THEMA"].ToString();
                bookingupdate[c].newlocation = rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString();
                if (rdr["STORNO"].ToString() != null)
                {
                    bookingupdate[c].deleted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bookingupdate[c].deleted = false;
                }
                c++;

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.Message + "\n\rStackTrace:\n\r" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    return bookingupdate;
}
```

the exeption is : Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Comment: What line does the error fall on?

Comment: Same question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849780/indexing-array-out-of-range-exception ??

Comment: its a different question with the same method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx)-Method closes the `DataReader`, hence a following call to `Read()` fails (well, that's excatly what the exception tells you).

Once you read the data into your `DataTable`, you could simply query it and use a `Select` projection to create your `BookingUpdate` instances (no need for the `while`-loop/`BookingUpdate[]`). So your code can basically trimmed down to

```
String command = "SELECT b.ID,b.VERANSTALTER, rr.VON ,rr.BIS, b.THEMA, b.STORNO, ra.BEZEICHNUNG from BUCHUNG b JOIN RESERVIERUNGRAUM rr on rr.BUCHUNG_ID = b.ID JOIN RAUM ra on ra.ID = rr.RAUM_ID WHERE b.UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD (DAY , -20 , getdate()) AND getdate() AND b.BOOKVERNR = 0";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()));
connection.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

var bookingupdate = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select (row => 
                    new BookingUpdate
                    {
                        bookingID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
                        fullUserName = row["VERANSTALTER"].ToString(),
                        newStart = (DateTime)row["VON"],
                        newEnd = (DateTime)row["BIS"],
                        newSubject = row["THEMA"].ToString(),
                        newlocation = row["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString(),
                        deleted = row["STORNO"].ToString() != null // note that this line makes no sense. If you can call `ToString` on an object, it is not 'null'
                    }).ToArray();

return bookingupdate;
```

*(Note: I omited the try-block for readability)*

You may also want to look into the [`DataRowExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348900.aspx), especially the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) method, to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable.Load(IDataReader)` closes reader after loading data from it. Use `DataTable` to get data you loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have already processed the reader at the following line due to which reader is at `EOF/Closed`:

```
dt.Load(rdr);
```

If you want to process the records after above method call, you *should* make use of your created `DataTable` object `dt` by above line unsing for loop with `dt.Rows.Count` *instead* of `while (rdr.Read())`

Checkout this topic from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)